# IntelliJ IDEA not able to download the sources

Tags: scala, maven, intellij-idea

Scala Maven Project in IntelliJ Idea is showing red lines in dependencies and Plugins.
How to get rid of these red lines?

[image]

Comment: Click the Maven refresh button. Are you behind a firewall? Then you need to set the appropriate proxy settings.

Comment: Yes, I am behind a firewall. I have started intelliJ Idea as administrator

Comment: Try to set the appropriate proxy settings in our IDE. Admin for IntelliJ IDEA may not be enough.

Comment: My Firewall has allowed the central repository link https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/   But Still i see red lines in IntelliJ

Comment: I would try it directly - without the IDEA. So with: mvn compile

Comment: And maybe check the pom.xml one more again.